# Could not simulate many users for DNS request

Tags: jmeter

I would like to simulate many users to browse a list of websites using JMeter.  Each users will use the same list of 1 million websites addresses stored in a .csv file (eg. google.com, facebook.com, yahoo.com..).

So I created "CSV Data Set Config", with Variable Names as 'hostname'.  Next I created a Thread Group with No. of Threads: 2 (for initial trial).

Under Thread Group, I created "HTTP Request", where the field "Web Server - Server Name or IP:" I entered '${hostname}/'.

Upon running it, it only made google.com and facebook.com request.  Apparently it did not run all the 1 million websites, and it also did not simulate 2 users.  If I changed the No. of Threads to 3, then it will only request google.com, facebook.com and yahoo.com.

Can anyone pls help how do I make it run the entire 1 million website HTTP request and simulate more than 1 user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to generate 1 million web requests from single machine, better to do [**JMeter Distributed Testing**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf). You can achieve 1 million web requests by increasing the **Number of Threads(users)** and **Loop Count** in Thread Group element or you can add **Loop Controller**.(Logic Controller)

For example:
Number of Threads: 100

Loop Count: 10

will generate 100*10=1000 web requests and for each request, 1000 entries will be read from csv file sequentially. 100 threads/users will create concurrent 100 threads/users and each thread will iterate for 10 times.(1000 web requests are not generated simultaneously.)If you have a machine of good configuration, you can try to generate 1 million web requests(if it is not hanged) otherwise do JMeter Distributed Testing.

If you don not want concurrent users, you can set Number of Threads: 1

Loop Count: Forever  in Thread Group and Stop thread on EOF in CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: Nidheesh, your clear explanation helped me understand it now.  Thank you so much!